# Dealing with several variables in various survey samples

Tags: r, survey

I have more than 10 survey samples (each one is a svydesign object) of which I need to calculate some proportions of several variables. The way I thought it would be more efficient to do this would be through looping, since I can't use `svymean(~var1+var2, data)` because *var2* is NA for some specifics *var1* values, so if I use `na.rm = TRUE` I lose some *var1* information and if I don't *var2* will result in a NA.

I tried to create a function like this:

```
svymean_all <- function(data, ...) {
  x <- c(...)
  for (i in length(x)) {
     svymean(x[i], data)
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

### Trying to be more specific

```
# download data
library(lodown)
pnad_cat <- get_catalog("pnad", output_dir = file.path(path.expand( "~" ), "PNAD"))
pnad_cat <- subset( pnad_cat , year >= 2001 )
pnad_cat <- lodown( "pnad" , pnad_cat )

options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
library(survey)

# Here is the first part that I think is inefficient
# I have to do this for every variable I want
result1 <- as.list(NULL)
result2 <- as.list(NULL)

# do the analysis for each year
for (i in 1:nrow(pnad_cat)) {
  pnad_df <- readRDS( pnad_cat[ i , 'output_filename' ] )
  pop_types <- data.frame(v4609 = unique(pnad_df$v4609), 
                          Freq = unique(pnad_df$v4609))

  prestratified_design <- svydesign(id = ~v4618,
                                    strata = ~v4617,
                                    data = pnad_df,
                                    weights = ~pre_wgt,
                                    nest = TRUE)

  rm(pnad_df) ; gc()

  pnad_design <- postStratify(design = prestratified_design,
                              strata = ~v4609,
                              population = pop_types)

  rm(prestratified_design) ; gc()


  # Here is the second part that I think is inefficient
  result1[[i]] <- svymean(~v0602, pnad_design, na.rm = TRUE)
  result2[[i]] <- svymean(~v6002, pnad_design, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

I should do something like this for many variables and conditions, using some subsets, not just v0602 and v6002. Is there any way to do this in a simpler way?